# How to properly store checkbutton variables in a list to be identified in a later function of the program?

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

Below is a portion of my whole program that I am having trouble with. The issue lies within the usage of the Tkinter Checkbuttons. I am attempting to create a program that takes a list of operations selected by the user and depending on the number of "operators" create checkbuttons that can be checked to identify what operations are run by which operator, identified by the status of the corresponding checkbutton state. But unfortunately the only responses I have been getting is error codes caused by my usage of IntVar() I believe,

Here is the output of the below code:

> Tkinter.IntVar instance at 0x000000000EE332C8

The desired output [for this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffO0W.png) is essentially what is shown in the below blockquote

> Variable status = 1, Op1, operator#1

```
import Tkinter
import Tkinter as tk
from Tkinter import *


class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        self.createWidgets()

    def createWidgets(self):

        operator = int(6) #assigned for testing
        lookingFor = ['op1','op2','op3','op4'] #assigned for testing
        self.checkList = [] #creating an empty list to store Checkbox variables

        cx,cy=0,0
        for x in range(0, operator):  ##creating left Lables
            cy+=1
            cx+=1
            label = Label(root)
            labelName = 'Operator#'
            label["text"] = str(labelName)+str(cy)
            label.grid(row=cx+1,column=0)

        cx,cy=0,0
        for y in lookingFor:   ##creating top labels
            cy+=1
            label = Label(root)
            label["text"] = str(y)
            label.grid(row=cx+1,column=cy)

        cx,cy=0,0
        for y in range(0, operator):
            cx+=1
            for x in lookingFor: #creating checkboxes
                var = IntVar()
                c = Checkbutton(root, variable = var)
                cy+=1
                c.grid(row=cx+1,column=cy)
                self.checkList.append(var)

            cy=0

        self.button = Button(root)
        self.button["text"] = 'Done'
        self.button["command"] = self.states
        self.button.grid(row=0,column=0)

    def states(self):
        #This function should print out the state of each button
        #as well as its corresponding 'Op#' and 'operator#'
        #So the program can later decide which operations are performed
        #when the program passes through each operator
        print (self.checkList) 


root = tk.Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
root.attributes('-topmost', True)
x=10
y=5
root.geometry("+%d+%d" % (x, y))
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the print output you got is not an error code. If you print the `IntVar` object directly then you get such value, but if you want to print the value stored in `IntVar` then you need to call the `get()` method.

Now to get detailed output format as you have asked, you can use a list of lists like this for each operator.

```
class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        self.createWidgets()

    def createWidgets(self):

        operator = int(6) #assigned for testing
        lookingFor = ['op1','op2','op3','op4'] #assigned for testing
        self.checkList = [[] for idx in range(operator)] #creating an empty list of lists to store Checkbox variables

        cx,cy=0,0
        for x in range(0, operator):  ##creating left Lables
            cy+=1
            cx+=1
            label = Label(root)
            labelName = 'Operator#'
            label["text"] = str(labelName)+str(cy)
            label.grid(row=cx+1,column=0)

        cx,cy=0,0
        for y in lookingFor:   ##creating top labels
            cy+=1
            label = Label(root)
            label["text"] = str(y)
            label.grid(row=cx+1,column=cy)

        cx,cy=0,0
        for y in range(0, operator):
            cx+=1
            for x in lookingFor: #creating checkboxes
                var = IntVar()
                c = Checkbutton(root, variable = var)
                cy+=1
                c.grid(row=cx+1,column=cy)
                self.checkList[y].append(var)

            cy=0

        self.button = Button(root)
        self.button["text"] = 'Done'
        self.button["command"] = self.states
        self.button.grid(row=0,column=0)

    def states(self):
        #This function should print out the state of each button
        #as well as its corresponding 'Op#' and 'operator#'
        #So the program can later decide which operations are performed
        #when the program passes through each operator
        for i, lst in enumerate(self.checkList, 1):
            for j, op in enumerate(lst, 1):
                print("Variable status = {}, Op{}, operator#{}".format(op.get(), j, i))
```

This prints output like:

```
Variable status = 1, Op1, operator#1
Variable status = 0, Op2, operator#1
Variable status = 0, Op3, operator#1
Variable status = 0, Op4, operator#1
Variable status = 0, Op1, operator#2
Variable status = 1, Op2, operator#2
Variable status = 0, Op3, operator#2
Variable status = 0, Op4, operator#2
Variable status = 0, Op1, operator#3
Variable status = 0, Op2, operator#3
Variable status = 0, Op3, operator#3
Variable status = 1, Op4, operator#3
Variable status = 0, Op1, operator#4
Variable status = 0, Op2, operator#4
Variable status = 0, Op3, operator#4
Variable status = 1, Op4, operator#4
Variable status = 0, Op1, operator#5
Variable status = 0, Op2, operator#5
Variable status = 0, Op3, operator#5
Variable status = 0, Op4, operator#5
Variable status = 0, Op1, operator#6
Variable status = 1, Op2, operator#6
Variable status = 0, Op3, operator#6
Variable status = 0, Op4, operator#6
```

Comment: Works flawlessly! thank you! I would like to ask for some clarification on the usage of lists within a list. I have experimented with lists of lists before but always seem to get lost in the navigation of them. Do you have a good reference to study the usage of lists within lists concerning python? I have a feeling in this project i will need it

Comment: Sorry I don't have a specific reference with me for that, but I guess you should just try using it. You can always check some answers on StackOverflow on that topic to get you started.